# How to display month in date picker like quarterly (jan-Mar) in android

Tags: java, android

I need to create a date picker which displays dates in quarterly like jan-Mar,April-jul and so on.Please any one is having idea suggest me.Thanks In Advance.

Thanks
Deepthi

Comment: refer the below link it's help you
http://androidexample.com/In_this_example_creating_a_date_picker_to_pick_day__month_year_of_date/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=89&aaid=113

Comment: The above link is not working can you please check it and give me suggestion or give any sample

Comment: Not like this.it should show in dialog only